# INDEX with array formula is giving different results than INDIRECT with ADDRESS when used by COUNTA

Tags: microsoft-excel

The following sheet illustrates the problem:

[image]

I want to know if there is any non-blank cell in a range, but once the sheet is autogenerated, I can't refer to this range directly (`B3:B5`). It is relative to some column.

Due to performance reasons, I want to use the `INDEX` function instead of `INDIRECT`, but when I pass the `INDEX` result to `COUNTA`, I am getting 3 non-blank cells when I just have 2.

Why `COUNTA(INDEX($1:$24, {3;4;5}, 2))` gives a different result than `COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, 2) & ":" & ADDRESS(5, 2)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because INDEX returns an array to the counta:

[image]

and the blank cell is `0` in the array, where as Indirect returns a range:

[image]

In the array the `0` counts as `1` but since the second refers to a range it sees B4 as empty and does not count it.

---

We can still use INDEX and return an address to the counta:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX($1:$24, 3, 2):INDEX($1:$24, 5, 2))
```

This has the luxury of not being volatile and still seeing B4 as empty.

[image]

Comment: This helped me a lot. Many thanks!